# How to predict a variable in python using previous data contained in excel?

Tags: python, excel, database, data-science, prediction

I have a specific algorithm I execute in Python.
This algorithm uses 3 variables: `x`, `y` and `z`.
These variables affect the time needed to execute the algorithm.
I used Python to write the data to an excel worksheet (using openpyxl)
This is an example of how it looks like:

| x | y | z | time in seconds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1200 | 15000 | 1500 | 800 |
| 900 | 20000 | 1800 | 900 |
| 1300 | 20000 | 1800 | 1100 |

I would like to print, in Python, the estimated time needed to execute the algorithm before execution, so the user knows how long he has to wait.

Edit for clarification: I would like to predict the needed time from a given x, y and z.

How can I do this?
Can I do it in excel, and read the value in Python?
Or is there a way to do it in Python?

I am looking for a simple and compact solution that delivers decent results, rather than a complicated solution that delivers very accurate results.

Edit: I am **not** looking for a written and ready to implement solution. A name of a method or just a place to start searching would be nice as I have never done this before.

Comment: I don't understand. Your question is basically how to read the column `time in seconds` from the Excel using Python?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please take some time to read [ask] and [mcve] you need to ask a very specific question providing a sample input and output along with your own effort. This question is more along the lines of. "This is my problem, provide a solution" SO is not a code writing service

Comment: Edited my question to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

On the specific table you posted,

```
t = 0.5 * x + 0.105 * y -0.9167 * z
```

But each CPU has different speeds, so the time would be different for each user, and you will need to run a benchmark on the user's computer.

You appear to have run 3 benchmarks. If you have more, then you will have more equations than unknowns, so you would need to do a multivariate linear regression to get a relationship between x,y,z and time

Comment: Thanks, these were actually just an example. I can create as many benchmarks as I want by running the algorithm. I'll look into "multivariate linear regression" then.
Does it also work if the relationship between the variables and time is exponential and not linear? So by increasing x, time increases exponentially for example?

Comment: If it is exponential, taking the logarithm may linearize the problem. But there must exist libraries that try different families of functions to find one that best fit the data. Try multivariate polynomial regression.